# Why isn't my MenuItem clickable?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've got a MenuItem with a label and a callback set, and it still isn't working, what do I need to do?

```
Menu* menu = Menu::create();

Label* lbl = Label::createWithTTF("My Label",  "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 25);
MenuItemLabel* item_label = MenuItemLabel::create(lbl);
item_label->setCallback(callback);

MenuItem* menu_item = MenuItem::create();
menu_item->addChild(item_label);

menu->addChild(menu_item);

myLayer->addChild(menu);
```

Even adding the callback to the `menu_item` doesn't change anything. What do I need to do to get my menu clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `MenuItemLabel` is not a label for a `MenuItem`, but a subclass of it. So I guess what happens is that despite seeing your label on screen is that the MenuItem click and looks for it's own `callback` and since it doesn't finds NULL or whatever it doesn't try to look any of its children, who might have it, or that it's size is 0, so you could never click on it.

Anyway, I'm not exactly clear on the details, only that in order to fix the issue, you need to remove the instance of `MenuItem` and only use `MenuItemLabel`:

```
Menu* menu = Menu::create();

Label* lbl = Label::createWithTTF("My Label",  "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 25);
MenuItemLabel* item_label = MenuItemLabel::create(lbl);
item_label->setCallback(callback);

menu->addChild(item_label);

myLayer->addChild(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this: i checked, its working in cocos2d-x 3.2 .

auto Label = Label::createWithSystemFont("My Label", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 25);
auto BtnItem = MenuItemLabel::create(Label,  CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::myCallback, this));

Menu* mymenu = Menu::create(BtnItem, NULL);

mymenu->setPosition(Vec2(WinSize.width/2,WinSize.height/2));

this->addChild(mymenu,1);


void HelloWorld::myCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
 CCLOG("Your Callback ");
}
```

Comment: Careful, if this even compiles, you're overwriting the name `Label` and `Menu`.

Comment: @TankorSmash can you please elaborate on what you want to say .  I am not getting your point.

Comment: You're redefining `Menu` as a variable name, but its originally a class. It's like doing `int int = 1`

Comment: @TankorSmash  so according to you , i can directly use my MenuitemLabel without adding it to my Menu .. is that so !!!?

Comment: so it will work nicely if i just replace my Menu name to some other name then Menu .. Right ?   Like Menu *mymenu instead Menu * Menu ...... !!?

Comment: Yeah, assuming you're not wrong about it working when you checked it the first time.